# In DataFrame "to_sql()", how to write NULL instead of None to Microsoft SQL?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas

I have a DataFrame with COVID-19 related data.

Here is an example row of said data

```
('Afghanistan', 'Confirmed', None, None, None, None, None, '2020-03-28', 1, 110.0, 100, 7, '2020-11-03'),
```

I am setting up the connection the following way:

```
  quoted = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={.../msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-17.6.so.1.1};SERVER=******;DATABASE=****;uid=***;pwd=***")
  engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))
  con = engine.connect()
```

I then try to write to the db

```
  df.to_sql('THE_TABLE', con = con, if_exists = 'append',index=False,schema='cd')
```

Which throws the following error

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The 
incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parame$

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 
17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) pr$
[SQL: INSERT INTO cd.[EXT_DOUBLING_RATE] ([Country_Region], [Case_Type], [Doubling Rate], 
[Coefficient], [Intercept], p_value, [R_squared], [Date], [Days normalized], [Cases], [Cutoff value], 
[Window s$
[parameters: (('Afghanistan', 'Confirmed', None, None, None, None, None, '2020-03-27', 0, 110.0, 100, 
7, '2020-11-06'), ('Afghanistan', 'Confirmed', None, None, None, None, None, '2020-03-28', 1, 110.0$
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

It seems that it has to do with the values of `None` because if try and insert the exact same row straight in the Database Tool with the value `NULL` instead of `None` it works.

So how do I push the data to the Microsoft SQL database such that it understands that `None` is `NULL`?

This is the output from `df.info()`

```
Data columns (total 13 columns):
Country_Region         69182 non-null object
Case_Type              69182 non-null object
Doubling Rate          63752 non-null float64
Coefficient            67140 non-null float64
Intercept              67140 non-null float64
p_value                67042 non-null float64
R_squared              63752 non-null float64
Date                   69182 non-null object
Days normalized        69182 non-null int64
Cases                  69182 non-null float64
Cutoff value           69182 non-null int64
Window size            69182 non-null int64
Script Refresh Date    69182 non-null object
dtypes: float64(6), int64(3), object(4)
```

Comment: Can you please check the dtype of all ```None```? Better yet, edit your question with the ```df.info()```.

Comment: Added "df.info()"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems, as you say to be some issue with the `None`. But there is a work around by replacing all `None` with `NaN` before writing to the DB. Here is an example. I create a DB to write to.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
```

Create some dataframe df with None values

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(5,3))
df2 = df.where(df < .2, None)
```

which gives

```
0   0.178066    None    0.00600411
1   None    0.0294849   None
2   None    0.00374341  None
3   None        None    None
4   0.182899    None    None
```

Replace all None with NaN

```
DF = df2.fillna(value=np.nan)
```

which give

```
     0            1       2     
0   0.178066    NaN       0.006004
1   NaN         0.029485  NaN
2   NaN         0.003743  NaN
3   NaN          NaN      NaN
4   0.182899     NaN      NaN
```

Now  some cosmethics

```
DF =DF.rename(columns = {0:'a', 1:'b',2:'c'})
```

In this step I create a DB to upload the stuff to to test and upload the DF

```
database = create_engine('sqlite:///database.db', echo=False)
DF.to_sql("FACTS2", if_exists = 'replace',con=database)
```

Now...If what is uploaded are NULL then any query on NULL should return what is NULL.

```
result = csv_database.execute("SELECT a, b, c FROM FACTS2 where a is NULL")
```

The result can then be read in pandas as a df as

```
pd.DataFrame(result)
```

Which is

```
    a       b           c
0   None    0.029485    None
1   None    0.003743    None
2   None    NaN         None
```

Conclusion: NULL are being written to your DB. So the key to solving your problem is simply `DF = df2.fillna(value=np.nan)`. Note the strange thing that can happen though. In column `b` (which is not entirely NULL AFTER the query, the NULL are written as NaN in the pandas DataFrame. This is NOT a problem in itself. The follwing query shows that there is nothing dodgy about how they are stored in the DB:

```
result = csv_database.execute("SELECT a, b, c FROM FACTS2 where b is NULL")
```

giving

```
      a         b       c
0   0.178066    None    0.006004
1   NaN         None    NaN
2   0.182899    None    NaN
```

This is a known issue.